# Node.JS not serving port 80 on IIS

Tags: node.js

I stopped IIS on Windows Server 2019 completely, and Im serving my NodeJS app on port 80 as follows:

```
const express= require('express');
const app=express();
...
...
...
const hostname = '0.0.0.0';
const port = 80;
app.listen(port, hostname, () => {
        console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

But Node is not serving remotely. It works with localhost:80

Ive set hostname = '0.0.0.0' based on an answer I've found here at StackOverflow. The server's public IP doesn't work either.

When turning IIS on and setting up the site, I can see an index.html file just fine, so port 80 works.

Is it a server issue, or a node.js issue?

Im starting node with

```
node index.js
```

Thanks.

Comment: If IIS is running then port 80 is occupied and you cannot do this. Use another port. Configure IIS to forward to it. IIS may engage firewall rules that your Node process does not.

Comment: I believe you are correct. I enabled port 3000 on the firewall and it works remotely. Would be a bad practice to delete the current rule for port 80 and create a new one? The IIS service is down when I am running node.js but as said, it still doesn't work.

Comment: I'd set up IIS to forward to your Node app vs. exposing it directly.

Comment: Im installing Application Request Routing extension and URL rewrite. I will let you know as soon as I finish. Thanks Tadman.

Comment: Tadman. I added a reverse proxy rule and it is working perfect. It also worked when I added a rule to open port 80 without deleting the default rule, but I toke your advice, and I forwarded IIS to my Node app. Other community users may run into the same issue, I would like to accept your answer to help others, but I believe SO will not let me accept a comment as an answer, correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those facing this issue, I fixed it up as Tadman recommended on the above comments: configuring IIS for forwarding (by installing the Application Request Routing and the URL rewrite extensions to IIS).

Node.js also worked when creating a new rule at Windows firewall for enabling port 80. The default rule at the firewall for port 80 will work only with IIS, not with Node.js.

As for the extensions mentioned above, here is a good instructive about how to install and setup:

https://dev.to/petereysermans/hosting-a-node-js-application-on-windows-with-iis-as-reverse-proxy-397b